# How to create a device dependant bitmap with a resolution matching the selected printer

Tags: printing, bitmap, gdi, dpi

I'm working on a tool to help our customer print labels. I made all the changes we wanted to to support color and transparency. Everything works even printing but...

When printing text, it is visible that the font quality is not optimal. I'm using an intermediary bitmap to sandwich each layer of text and bitmap needed to create the final result then copy it to correct location on the printer.canvas.

Using the previous version of our tool, the text is crisp but with the new version the text is coarser.

The only difference I can find between the printer canvas and my bitmap canvas is the dpi. The printer has 600x600 dpi, my canvas 96 by 96.

Everything I do is made to measure what it should for the printer dpi. I mean I don't resize my bitmap to match the printer size. So it is not what cause the loss of quality.

I try CreateCompatibleBitmap with the printer.canvas hoping to get a new bitmap with the same characteristic of the printer canvas. But I found out that my bitmap is still 96x96 dpi and the 600x600 dpi of the printer. So how can I create a bitmap (device dependant or not) with a dpi of 600x600 that should make my font print to the perfection? Because I tried to quadruple the size of my label then use StretchDIBits to get it back to normal size. It gave me almost perfect result. But I ran into memory problem and strange behaviour (completely black canvas). Unless there is something that I ignore on that matter.

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Removed the HTML5 canvas tag as this seem to be GDI only.

Comment: I never mention any HTML tag, it is GDI programming for windows. Thanks for your time.

Comment: the canvas tag is for html5 canvas.